# Having issues with my program

Tags: java

Having some issues with the code was wondering if any one can help. Currently the issue that is coming up is when you run the program it takes the commands fine the counter counts up but it is not adding the numbers together for the sum so with out the sum the average will not work plz help. Im using Eclipse.

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class GPA extends JDialog
        implements ActionListener,
        PropertyChangeListener {
 

    private String typedText = null;
    private JTextField textField;
    private String magicWord;
    private JOptionPane optionPane;
    private String btnString1 = "Next Grade";
    private String btnString2 = "Average";
    private String btnString3 = "Exit";
    ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;
    int gradeCounter = 0;
    int average = 0;

    /**
     * Returns null if the typed string was invalid; otherwise, returns the
     * string as the user entered it.
     */
    public String getValidatedText() {
        return typedText;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the reusable dialog.
     */
    public GPA(Frame aFrame, String aWord) {
        super(aFrame, true);

        magicWord = aWord.toUpperCase();
        setTitle("Average Grades");

        textField = new JTextField(10);

        //Create an array of the text and components to be displayed.
        String msgString1 = "Please enter a grade (0-100)";
        Object[] array = {msgString1, textField};

        //Create an array specifying the number of dialog buttons
        //and their text.
        Object[] options = {btnString1, btnString2, btnString3,};

        //Create the JOptionPane.
        optionPane = new JOptionPane(array,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                null,
                options,
                options[0]);

        //Make this dialog display it.
        setContentPane(optionPane);

        //Handle window closing correctly.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        //Ensure the text field always gets the first focus.
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ce) {
                textField.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        //Register an event handler that puts the text into the option pane.
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        //Register an event handler that reacts to option pane state changes.
        optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        pack();
    }

    /**
     * This method handles events for the text field.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        optionPane.setValue(btnString1);
    }

    /**
     * This method reacts to state changes in the option pane.
     */
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String prop = e.getPropertyName();

        if (isVisible()
                && (e.getSource() == optionPane)
                && (JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop)
                || JOptionPane.INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop))) {
            Object value = optionPane.getValue();

            if (value == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                //ignore reset
                return;
            }

            //Reset the JOptionPane's value.
            //If you don't do this, then if the user
            //presses the same button next time, no
            //property change event will be fired.
            optionPane.setValue(
                    JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);

            if (btnString1.equals(value)) {
            int text = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                grades.add(text);
                textField.setText("");
                gradeCounter = gradeCounter ++ ;
                
                if (btnString2.equals(value)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); ++i) {
                   sum = grades.get (i) + grades.get(i++);
  
                }
                average = sum / gradeCounter;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sum);
                  
                    exit();
                }
        }else { //user closed dialog or clicked cancel
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sum);
                
                typedText = null;
                exit();
            }
        }
}

    /**
     * This method clears the dialog and hides it.
     */
    public void exit() {
        dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        //create JDialog and components on EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            public void run() {
                new GPA(null, "").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few small issue here that are causing you problems.

The `if (btnString1.equals(value)) {` does not have a corresponding `else` so when the second button is pressed the `btnString2` is not even called.

Secondly the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, average);` should be `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sum);` Currently it only displays the sum not the average.

Finally `gradeCounter = gradeCounter ++ ;` can be set to just `gradeCounter ++ ;` As it is the gradeCounter does not increment. The `++` operator will increment the counter without having to set it again using `=`.

There is also an error with the average calculation where the `sum = grades.get(i) + grades.get(i++)` is not needed. As there is a `for` statement around it, it will loop through all the grades in the list anyway. It is best to just say `sum += grades.get(i);`

Here is the new part of code that has been changed.

```
if (btnString1.equals(value)) {
    int text = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
    grades.add(text);
    textField.setText("");
    gradeCounter ++ ;
} else if (btnString2.equals(value)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); ++i) {
       sum += grades.get (i);
    }
    average = sum / gradeCounter;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, average);

    exit();

}
```

Comment: I tried this and now all it is doing is showing the display for the average it wont show the display were i input information and it wont let me close the display box.

Comment: I have just run this again and had no problems. I was able to show the display and input numbers and get back an average. Did you have any issues with this before?

Comment: the only issue i was having was the one i said. Do you think u can send me the full version of the code ur using incase im inputing it wrong or somthing?

Comment: NVM mind man Just got it to work omg thanks. Me and a friend spent hours on this thing.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. Using the debugger in Eclipse is a very powerful tool. It helps a lot when you get into situations like this. You can accept my answer now then :)